# How can we use new View.OnClickListener directly when OnCLickListener is not static

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I was wondering one thing today. Whenever we are setting up a `ClickListener`, we run this code.

```js
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

  }
});
```

I Opened the View Class and saw the `OnClickListener` interface and found that it is `not static`. The method is like this:

```js
public interface OnClickListener {
  /**
   * Called when a view has been clicked.
   *
   * @param v The view that was clicked.
   */
  void onClick(View v);
}
```

Then how are we able to access `OnClickListener` method directly by using class name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For java, "A nested interface is implicitly static." [jls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-9.html) (9.1.1.3)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement class `View.OnClickListener` and then you will able to `Override` its method just like shown below :

```
public class YourActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

  }
}
```